# Convert JSON key values to CSV

Tags: ruby, json, csv

My goal is to read a CSV file, get each ID from that file's records, use each ID into the Meetup API URL and then create a new CSV file with certain values from the JSON response.

Here's what I have so far:

```
require "net/https"
require "uri"
require 'csv'
require 'json'

membersCSV = CSV.foreach('id-members-meetup.csv') do |row|
id = row[1]
uri = URI.parse("https://api.meetup.com/2/members?order=name&member_id=" + id + "&format=json&key=MY_KEY")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
response = http.request(request)
CSV.open("ghmeetup.csv", "w", {:col_sep => ";"}) do |csv|
  JSON.parse(response.body)["other_services"].each do |single|
    csv << [single["twitter"]["identifier"], single["facebook"]["identifier"], single["linkedin"]["identifier"]]
  end
end
end
```

And this is the error I get:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse': 757: (JSON::ParserError) '<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>cloudflare-nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.2/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
    from ghmeetup.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1266:in `open'
    from ghmeetup.rb:12:in `block in <main>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1716:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1120:in `block in foreach'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1266:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/csv.rb:1119:in `foreach'
    from ghmeetup.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

What do you think?

**EDIT**

```
require "uri"
require 'csv'
require 'json'
require 'net/http'

ghCSV = CSV.foreach('id-gh-meetup.csv') do |row|
    id = row[1]
    key="KEY" 
    uri = URI.parse("https://api.meetup.com/2/members?order=name&member_id=#{id}&format=json&key=#{key}")
    Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: true) do |http|
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
    response = http.request request
    parseResponse = JSON.parse(response.body)['results'][0]
    p "working"
      CSV.open("ghmeetup.csv", "w") do |csv|
        p "working 2"       
            parseResponse.each do |single|
                p "working 3"
              csv << single
            end
        end
    end
end
```

So it works if I keep only JSON.parse(response.body) but when I add ['results'][0] in parseResponse I get this error:

```
ghmeetup.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

This is the JSON structure, I want to target [results][0].other_services.twitter.identifier

```
{
results: [
 - {
   - other_services: {
      twitter: {
        identifier: "@HugoAmsellem"
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you try with  http.use_ssl = true ?

Comment: Yep :/ still got the same error

Comment: I suggest you pare down your question code. What happens if you require 'net/http', then omit the CSV, the loop, and the JSON? For example, if you try to fetch just one member, what response body do you get?

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is enabled for an HTTP connection by `#use_ssl=`

This code gets a successful response on my system using Ruby 2.2.0:

```
require 'net/http'  # Not HTTPS
key="..."  # Get your personal API key from Meetup
uri = URI.parse("https://api.meetup.com/2/members?order=name&member_id=1&format=json&key=#{key}")
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: true) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
  response = http.request request
  p response.body
end
```

In previous versions of Ruby you would need to `require 'net/https'` to use HTTPS. This is [no longer true](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html).

Can you try the code above on your system?

If it works, great. If it doesn't work, then you can simplify your question code, such as omitting the CSV, the loop, the JSON, etc.

Comment: Edit out more, if you can, to trigger the erorr with the least-possible code. Also, change from require 'net/https' to 'net/http'. You may want to omit your API key.